# How to capture a substring from each lines of a file using grep?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, gnu

How to capture specific substring from each line of a file when the required substring is at the end of each line.

code

```
sed 's/.*\(by user [0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/p' file > output
```

```
$cat file 
2021-04-02 [Information] read first line from file - Reviewing by user skha12
2022-04-29 09:45:14,754 [1426] [Information] This is a single line
2021-04-02 [debugging] read first line from file - Reviewing by user nar73h
2021-04-02 [Information] read first line from file - Editing by user abcxxs
2022-04-29 09:45:14,754 [1426] [Information] This is a single line
2021-04-02 [debugging] read first line from file - Reviewing by user Y54321
2022-04-29 08:49:12,554 [143] [debugging]  This is a single line
2022-04-29 09:40:13,852 [5]  [Information] This is a single line
2022-04-29 09:45:14,754 [1426] [Information] This is a single line
```

expected output

```
nar73h
skha12
abcxxs
Y54321
```

Comment: Just change place of your capturing group in `sed` and you are all set. Try like: `sed 's/.*by user \([0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/p' file` once OR with `sed`'s `-E` option try `sed -E 's/.*by user ([0-9a-zA-Z]*).*/\1/p' file`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `grep` for this? Your script containing `\(by user [0-9a-zA-Z]*\)` would output `by user skha12` - I assume it's obvious to you how to tweak that to output just `skha12` instead so what's wrong with just doing that?

Comment: Thats right @EdMorton. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @felcitiy you're welcome but I was actually asking a question - why do you want to use `grep` instead of just tweaking your `sed` script instead?

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' input_file
skha12
nar73h
abcxxs
Y54321
```

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.* //' input_-file
skha12
nar73h
abcxxs
Y54321
```

Answer (score 2):

**grep**:

```
<file grep 'by user' | grep -o '[^ ]\+$'
```

**cut**:

```
<file grep 'by user' | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

**sed**:

```
<file sed -n '/by user/ s/.* //p'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/by user/{print $NF}' file
skha12
nar73h
abcxxs
Y54321
```

```
$ sed -n 's/.*by user //p' file
skha12
nar73h
abcxxs
Y54321
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `gnu grep`, and the required substring is at the end of each line:

```
grep -oP ".*\bby\h+user\h+\K[0-9a-zA-Z]+$" file > output
```

**Explanation**

- `.*` Match the whole lines
- `\bby\h+user\h+` A word boundary, then match `by user`  with 1 or more spaces
- `\K` Clear the current match buffer (forget what is matched so far)
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ times any of the ranges in the character class
- `$` End of string

The file *output* contains:

```
skha12
nar73h
abcxxs
Y54321
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I used to get the expected output using grep -

```
grep "by user" file | awk '{print $NF}' > output
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. You never need grep when you're using awk and since every line of your sample input contains `by user` you don't need to search for it. If that's not really the case then edit your question to fix your sample input to also include lines that do not contain `by user`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -alnE'say $F[-1] if /by user/' file 

grep -oP '(?<=by user ).*' file
```